# Bootstrap Form Control with React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have the following component with made with react-bootstrap

```
class TextInput extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      name,
      label,
      value,
      required,
      handleChange,
      t,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Form.Label>{label}</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          data-testid={"text-input"}
          id={name}
          value={value}
          name={name}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

TextInput.propTypes = {
  handleChange: PropTypes.func,
  name: PropTypes.string,
};

export default withTranslation()(TextInput);
```

When I try to run my test below, I get the following error:

TestingLibraryElementError:

`Found a label with the text of: /this is a test/i, however no form control was found associated to that label. Make sure you're using the "for" attribute or "aria-labelledby" attribute correctly.`

How should I be properly testing controlled bootstrap components?

```
describe('TextInput', () => {

  const defaultProps = { 
    name: "Title",
    label: "Body",
    type: "text",
    value: "this is a test",
    required: false,
    handleChange:jest.fn(),
  };

  it("Renders TextInput Component with correct values", ()=>{
    render(
      <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
        <TextInput {...defaultProps}/>
      </I18nextProvider>
      )
    screen.debug();
    expect(screen.queryByTestId("text-input")).toBeTruthy();

    const textValue = screen.getByLabelText(/this is a test/i);
    expect(textValue).toBeInTheDocument(); 
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the "**htmlFor**" attribute inside <Form.Label>

and pass the **id** attribute inside <Form.Control> with the same name of htmlFor

The for or htmlFor attribute is used in labels. It refers to the id of the element this label is associated with.

For example:

```
<>
  <Form.Label htmlFor="exampleColorInput">Color picker</Form.Label>
  <Form.Control
    type="color"
    id="exampleColorInput"
    defaultValue="#563d7c"
    title="Choose your color"
  />
</>
```

You can see more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp